# When was the first time that logistic regression was used to forecast an unknown outcome?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, forecasting, history

Logistic regression is originally used to predict probabilities of a binary response or further used to forecast the binary response for unknown responses based on a test data set. I was wondering when was the first time that logistic regression was used to make a forecast about an unknown outcome as a method of machine learning.

Comment: Logistic regression has been long used in statistics, probably longer than the term machine learning has been around. Are you asking when logistic regression was first developed? Because that would be in 1958 by David Cox.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! To my understanding David Cox (1958) developed LR in order to interpret the influence of other IVs on a binary DV and not for a classification problem. I would like to know, the first use of the logistic regression methodology to predict a response variable (based on a training set) for new cases, where the response is unknown.

Comment: You could do that just the same with a model used for inference. There is no mathematical difference between the two.

Comment: My question is not about the mathematical difference but about the different field of application, meaning when was the first time that logistic regression was trained on a data set to predict unknown responses.

Comment: Then I don't think there will be a more definitive answer than the one already given by @TinderForMidgets. I can't imagine it not being used for that purpose right after its conception

Comment: Okay thank you! According to the "origins of logistic regression" (@TinderForMidgets) McFadden in 1973 was the first one who linked logistic regression with discrete choice theory. This must be the basis to use logistic regression as classifier as it transfers probabilities into predicted Yes or No

Comment: That's one way to interpret it. Another is that David Cox already did that implicitly by using it in discriminant analysis in the 60's (page 11 of @TinderForMidgets' file, second paragraph: *"Between 1960 ... Cox (1969)"*). But I think it is fair to say that is was popularized in the 1970's.

Comment: But he did not used any cross-validation.

Answer (score 2):

It was probably used throughout the history of mathematics without formal documentation. David Cox invented it in 1958 but there was development of the logistic function dating back to the 19th century.

You can read about it [here](https://papers.tinbergen.nl/02119.pdf)

Comment: I think Sir David [not a relative, but I enjoy having the same name] would want to underline the work of Joseph Berkson and others in the 1940s. Jan Cramer wrote in some detail about the history of this and related models. e.g. https://philpapers.org/rec/JCRTEO

Comment: Thank you for the good references covering the development of logistic regression. But as far as I see logistic regression back then, was initially used for descriptive analyzation of the relation between an binary DV and some IVs and not applied for a classification problem based on a training set. Or am I wrong about a clear usage distinction of logistic regression between an econometric probability estimatior and a classifier for unknown cases.